# How to Set Permission for folders/files in iOS

Tags: ios, permissions, directory

How can I set permission to folders and files in iOS which is there inside documents folder?

Is it possible to set read only permission while creating files inside documents folder?

Or any alternative solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how you create the file, you can specify file attributes. To make a file read-only, pass the following attributes:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFilePosixPermissions : @(0444) };
```

Note the leading `0` in the value. That's important. It indicates that this is an octal number.

Another option is to set the file's attributes after it has been created:

```
NSString *path = ... // the path to the file
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error = nil;
if (![fm setAttributes:attributes ofItemAtPath:path error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to make %@ read-only: %@", path, error);
}
```

Update:

To ensure existing permissions are kept, do the following:

```
NSString *path = ... // the path to the file
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error = nil;
// Get the current permissions
NSDictionary *currentPerms = [fm attributesOfFileSystemForPath:path error:&error];
if (currentPerms) {
    // Update the permissions with the new permission
    NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [currentPerms mutableCopy];
    attributes[NSFilePosixPermissions] = @(0444);
    if (![fm setAttributes:attributes ofItemAtPath:path error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to make %@ read-only: %@", path, error);
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"Unable to read permissions for %@: %@", path, error);
}
```

Comment: Do you not need to get the existing attributes and merge the new attributes?

Comment: @David If the file has other specific attributes, then yes, that would be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks guys, will try and let you know my finding.

Comment: David, how to add the new permission to the existing permissions for that file ? Please post the code snippet.

Comment: @iOSEnthusiast I updated my answer with details on preserving existing permissions.

Comment: @rmaddy much helpful.

Comment: When i try to access the folders or files via iFunbox app still am able to perform Read/Write operations. How can i get rid of iFunbox access?

Comment: Worth noting that you can make files read-only using the NSFileAppendOnly attribute. (Crazy name) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfileappendonly?language=objc